# opencv2\contrib\contrib.hpp not found in OpenCV 3.1.0

Tags: c++, opencv, face

opencv2\contrib\contrib.hpp not found in OpenCV 3.1.0

```
Ptr<FaceRecognizer>  model = createEigenFaceRecognizer();
//train data
model->train(images, labels);

model->save("E:/FDB/yaml/eigenface.yml");
```

also not fount FaceRecognizerenter,createEigenFaceRecognizer() train and save 
please help me

Comment: Did you build opencv with `opencv_contrib`?

Comment: Can you guide me to build opencv_contrid?
I have tried do but it is fail

Comment: Did you follow the instruction at [github](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib). You can also download the contents of `modules` directory to your `opencv` source's `modules`.

Comment: Thanks uncle :) i have done install the modules extra contrid but it also not fount FaceRecognizerenter,createEigenFaceRecognizer() train and save ..